# Laravel multiple checkbox data fetch

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have got a serious problem about fetching data into the view after getting all the values from multiple checkboxes. I can fetch the last value checked, but no more.

Here's my controller:

```
public function getFilterPaytv(){

    $valore =  Input::get('opt');
    if(!empty($valore))
    foreach ($valore as $val) {

        $results = Tpaytv::where('Desc', 'LIKE', '%' . $val . '%')->get();

        echo $val . ""; // 

        // echo $results
    }

    return View::make('result')->with('results', $results);
}
```

and here's my view

```
@if($results->count())
    @foreach($results as $pa)

            <div class="col-lg-12 ">
               <div class="box">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-2"><img src="img/T.png" class="timC"></div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <ul class="boxCar">
                        <li>Pro: {{$pa->Type}}</li>
                        <li>Sca: {{ date("d/m/Y",strtotime($pa -> S))}}</li>
                        <li 
                             data-toggle="modal" 
                             data-target="#{{ $pa->id }}">
                             <a>Magg</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                      <!--inizio modal -->

                  <!-- fine modal -->
                  <div class="col-lg-3"><h1 class="ads">{{$pa->T}}€</h1></div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">

                   {{ 
                       link_to_route('confr.show',
                       'request ', 
                       array($paytv->id), 
                       array('class' => 'btn btn-green btn-md offButton'))
                   }}
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    @endforeach
@else
no
@endif
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking and how it fits in with the code you posted. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish and point out where it's happening in your code?

Comment: i just want to get all checkboxes checked and execute a search query with those value.. after that i want to diplay all results -- its simple, i mean it seems simple :)

Comment: Ah, so in the line `$valore =  Input::get('opt');`, opt contains an array of checkbox values coming in from a different view?

Answer (score 1):

There are still a number of issues with your code that need to be addressed, but the reason why you're only getting the last result of the checkbox set, assuming that the checkbox values are coming from `$valore = Input::get('opt');`, is because when you loop through the values in your foreach, you're overwriting your results variable.

In your code:

```
foreach ($valore as $val) {

    $results = Tpaytv::where('Desc', 'LIKE', '%' . $val . '%')->get();

    echo $val . ""; // 

    // echo $results
}
```

The variable `$result` has not been declared until the first iteration of your loop which means that in your first loop `$result` is set to the result of your `Tpaytv::where` method call and then on the second loop the value in `$result` is being **overwritten** by the next result from the `Tpaytv::where` method call. This is why you're only getting the last value checked; it's the last value looped over in your foreach.

If you want to get a sack of results, you need to declare the `$result` variable as an empty array before the foreach loop and then push the results into the array:

```
// Create your empty array
$results = array();

foreach ($valore as $val) {

    // Push the results of the method call into the array.
    // This will keep them from being overwritten in your foreach loop. 
    $results[] = Tpaytv::where('Desc', 'LIKE', '%' . $val . '%')->get();

    echo $val . ""; // 

    // echo $results
}
```

Comment: all right then... but i still got the problem cause if i count($results) in my view, the app goes in fatal error --- "Call to a member function count() on a non-object" , im really confused

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. At the very top of your view try putting in `{{ dd($results) }}`. This will tell laravel to die and dump the contents of the variable to the browser. When you do so does it show your $results variable as an array with a series of objects in it?

Comment: yes ... array(2) { [0]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#562 ... etc etc

Comment: Are you counting by using `count($results)` or still `$results->count()`? Since you're passing back an array now you should count using the `count($results)`.

Comment: @if(count($results))
    @foreach($results as $pa) etc --- Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$type ---- with $type the debugger means $pa->type -- dont understand why fetchin everything else its working well but with that arry it doesnt works-- i really appreciate your help by the way

Comment: Np on the help. Something you may want to try is converting the collection to an array before you push it into your `$results` array: `$results = Tpaytv::where('Desc', 'LIKE', '%' . $val . '%')->get()->toArray();`. This way in your view you can walk through the entire thing as an array. It may make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: i know that method but it seems not works for that -- ive got my value as array , im doing a foreach for every value checked but it still seem getting error on count() method --Trying to get property of non-object this time , it makes me crazy, i dont want to handle the checkbox with js :\

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird  maybe try `@if(isset($results))` in place of `@if($results->count())`

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($friends as $friend)
 <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="{{$item}}" value="{{$itemval}}">
 @endforeach


$items_checked= Input::get('check');
 if(is_array($items_checked))
 {
    // do stuff with here with checked items
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.