# How to check if user has selected multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am working on a Laravel 5.8 project which is an Online Store. and in this project, I wanted to add "Printing Order Factors" feature for Admins.

So I have made a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('orders.newprint') }}">
    @csrf
    @forelse($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{ $order->ord_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->status_label }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->customer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->ord_total }}</td>
    </tr>
    @empty
        <td colspan="7" class="text-center">No order to show</td>
    @endforelse
</form>
```

So basically admins can select multiple orders like this:

[image]

And I'm trying to send order ids as an array:

`<input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">`

Now at the Controller, I need to check if user has selected multiple orders or not

```
public function prnpriview(Request $request)
    {
        if(!empty($request->input('actions'))){
            if($request->input('actions')=='print_factors'){
                if(USER SELECTES MORE THAN ONE CHECKBOX) { 
                    ...
                    return view('admin.shop.orders.newprint', compact('args'));
                }else{
                    return back();
                }
            }
        }else{
            return back();
        }
    }
```

So how to check if user has selected multiple checkboxes (more than one checkbox) or not ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel multiple checkbox data fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26512383/5882307)

Comment: So you have the selected checkboxes array in `$request->orderCheck`?

Comment: If you have selected one ore more checkboxes, `orderCheck` will be an array and if you do, for example `count($request->input('orderCheck')` it should return a number from `1` to infinity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$request->orderCheck` will be in an array, so you can use `count()`

```
$checked = $request->input('orderCheck',[]);// if checkbox is not checked than return empty array
if(count($checked) > 1) { 
    return view('admin.shop.orders.newprint', compact('args'));
}else{
    return back();
```

Comment: What would happen if no checkbox is checked?

Comment: It will return empty array